# HttpFormUrlEncodedContent not part of system.Net.Http

Tags: c#

I'm using the `HttpFormUrlEncodedContent` object in my application for a `PostAsync`.
I put all the necessary reference as :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
```

The following is the code to do my post:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task", task));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("merchant", "2234-6566"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ref", refl));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("hash", hash));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("amount", "20"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("seller", "mymail@mail.com"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("remarks", "payment")); 

HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
Task<HttpResponseMessage> t = client.PostAsync("https://epay.com/api/", content);
t.Wait();
var response = t.Result;
```

With this I get error message as below:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpFormUrlEncodedContent' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What could be the possible way to solve this issue?

Comment: That is because [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent) is from `Windows​.Web​.Http` which is for UWP application.

Answer (score 0):

That is because [HttpFormUrlEncodedContent Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent) is from `Windows​.Web​.Http` namespace which is for UWP application.

So if your program is in fact a UWP application then make sure that the required assembly is referenced and add the `using` for that namespace.

Otherwise just add the values collection to the [FormUrlEncodedContent Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.118).aspx)